# Tradingview PINE script plotshape or label on last 5 candle in case of condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]I want to make a label or shape on top of candle if I found an inside bar candle, comparing latest candle with last 5 candle.

I tried following code.
It didnt work as expected.

```
for i=1 to 5
   if (high < high[i] and low > low[i])
       label.new(bar_index, low, "S", yloc=yloc.belowbar, textcolor = color.white)


 second_candle = close
 myplot = false
 if(second_candle[1] > 0 or second_candle[2] > 0)
     myplot := true

inside_bar = high[1] > high and low[1] < low
candle_break = high > high[1]
special_candle = inside_bar[1] and candle_break and myplot

plotshape(special_candle, style=shape.circle, color=color.orange, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. In your first drawing, why the candle 5 is an inside bar ? ( It goes way outside the candle 2 and 3 )

Comment: latest canle high and low compared with last 5 candles if latest candle high is lower and low is higher than any candles (last 5) then we got a inside bar candle. I could not make it working with plotshape